# rename pivot columns using dateadd for column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, sql-server-2014

I have a table with a month offset number. I want to pivot on this column but for the output I want to calculate the month name/year using the offset.

I need to be able to do this without dynamic SQL that I have to `execute`.

In production my `MyMonthOffset` may go up to 24 (or more). I know in the `PIVOT` `FOR` part I'll have to list all of them like `FOR MyMonthOffset IN ("0", "1", "2", "3", ... "24")`.

## input table

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyData
(
      MyName        [NVARCHAR](10) NOT NULL
    , MyMonthOffset [INT]          NOT NULL
    , MyCount       [INT]          NOT NULL
) ON [DEFAULT];

INSERT INTO dbo.MyData
VALUES
    ('four', 0, 6),
    ('four', 1, 8),
    ('four', 1, 4),
    ('four', 2, 8),
    ('four', 2, 5),
    ('four', 2, 5),
    ('four', 3, 4),
    ('four', 3, 8),
    ('four', 3, 8),
    ('one', 0, 3),
    ('one', 0, 5),
    ('one', 0, 4),
    ('one', 0, 2),
    ('one', 1, 4),
    ('one', 2, 1),
    ('one', 2, 1),
    ('one', 3, 9),
    ('three', 1, 1),
    ('three', 3, 6),
    ('three', 3, 9),
    ('three', 3, 7),
    ('two', 0, 10),
    ('two', 0, 1),
    ('two', 1, 7),
    ('two', 3, 7)

+--------+---------------+---------+
| MYNAME | MYMONTHOFFSET | MYCOUNT |
+--------+---------------+---------+
| four   | 0             | 6       |
| four   | 1             | 8       |
| four   | 1             | 4       |
| four   | 2             | 8       |
| four   | 2             | 5       |
| four   | 2             | 5       |
| four   | 3             | 4       |
| four   | 3             | 8       |
| four   | 3             | 8       |
| one    | 0             | 3       |
| one    | 0             | 5       |
| one    | 0             | 4       |
| one    | 0             | 2       |
| one    | 1             | 4       |
| one    | 2             | 1       |
| one    | 2             | 1       |
| one    | 3             | 9       |
| three  | 1             | 1       |
| three  | 3             | 6       |
| three  | 3             | 9       |
| three  | 3             | 7       |
| two    | 0             | 10      |
| two    | 0             | 1       |
| two    | 1             | 7       |
| two    | 3             | 7       |
+--------+---------------+---------+
```

## current pivot output

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT
          MyName
        , MyMonthOffset
        , MyCount
    FROM dbo.MyData
) SourceTable
PIVOT
(
    SUM(MyCount)
    FOR MyMonthOffset IN ("0", "1", "2", "3")
) PivotTable

+--------+------+----+------+----+
| MYNAME |  0   | 1  |  2   | 3  |
+--------+------+----+------+----+
| four   | 6    | 12 | 18   | 20 |
| one    | 14   | 4  | 2    | 9  |
| three  | NULL | 1  | NULL | 22 |
| two    | 11   | 7  | NULL | 7  |
+--------+------+----+------+----+
```

## expected / desired output

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| MYNAME | JUL 18 | AUG 18 | SEP 18 | OCT 18 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| four   | 6      | 12     | 18     | 20     |
| one    | 14     | 4      | 2      | 9      |
| three  | NULL   | 1      | NULL   | 22     |
| two    | 11     | 7      | NULL   | 7      |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: Naming columns like that requires dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use *dynamic pivot*

Declare two variable one for pivot columns, another for alias column name.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @Pivotcols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);



SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',"'  + CAST(MyMonthOffset AS VARCHAR(5)) +'"'
            FROM MyData 
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


SET @Pivotcols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',[' + CAST(MyMonthOffset AS VARCHAR(5)) + '] as ''' + FORMAT(DATEADD(mm,MyMonthOffset,GETDATE()),'MMM yy') + ''''
            FROM MyData 
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')   


set @query = 'SELECT MyName, '+  @Pivotcols + '  
FROM
(
    SELECT
          MyName
        , MyMonthOffset
        , MyCount
    FROM dbo.MyData
) SourceTable
PIVOT
(
    SUM(MyCount)
    FOR MyMonthOffset IN ('+@cols+')
) PivotTable'

execute(@query)
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=31f0341cd3fd1ce31c9891c8516ee872)